# Positioning of JS Expanding Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expand

I'm building a menu that consists of a series of divs along the bottom of a header image which are designed to expand upward to a designated height when hovered over.

I've got a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DbTyX/18/) that nearly accomplishes what I'd like, but for some reason the div is jumping to the top of the container when the cursor is over it. I'm wondering what I'm missing in the JS (or possibly the CSS) that's causing the behavior. I've also included an image to help show the desired effect.

[image]

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `bottom: 0px` is already defined in the CSS, you don't need to define the `top` attribute when you animate. You can simply redefine the `height` and it will work as expected. Here is the example for that: http://jsfiddle.net/DbTyX/20/

```
$("#pagebuttonhome").hover(function() {
    $("#pagebuttonhome").animate({'height': '80px'});
}, function() {
    $("#pagebuttonhome").animate({'height': '30px'});
});
```

Just for optimization you can also use the `this` keyword:

```
$("#pagebuttonhome").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({'height': '80px'});
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({'height': '30px'});
});
```

Comment: Evan, I adjusted the CSS just a little (adding overflow:hidden) so a scrollbar wouldn't appear when the div was collapsed, and then your solution worked perfectly! The adjusted JSfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/YYG7j/4/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your JSFiddle, I'm not sure I see why you're animating the top property as well, the code without that:

```
$("#pagebuttonhome").hover(function() {
    $("#pagebuttonhome").animate({'height': '80px'});
}, function() {
    $("#pagebuttonhome").animate({'height': '30px'});
});
```

I believe works as you expect.

This is also accomplishable using CSS alone (with transitions) let me know if you're interested in that solution

**Note**: A CSS only solution is not compatible with any browser that doesn't support transitions

Answer (score 0):

If you set an element's `position` to `absolute` and then set the `top` or `left` value, then the values are interpreted as relative to the origin (0,0). Use `marginTop` / `marginLeft` instead, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DbTyX/18/).